# Use text in a cell as plus and minus

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with multiple rows. There is a cell on each row that says "In" and "Out" in a dropdown. Basically this is plus and minus. Next to that I have a cell that that holds an amount.

So it looks like this:

```
Item 1, In, 10
Item 2, Out, 5
```

This totals a profit of 5.

How can I with this setup calculate the total profit/loss for all the cells in the sheet depending on multiple in/out rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *if* formula will calculate the rows and a *sum* formula will calculate the column.

First make the numbers positive and negative values.

```
=IF(B2="In",C2,C2*-1)
```

This formula in 'D2' checks if the value of 'B2' is "In".

- If *yes* then just adds the value of 'C2'.
- If *no* then it multiplies the value of 'C2' by negative one.

Second step is to add up the numbers.

```
=SUM(D2:D3)
```

Cell 'D4' sums the column.

[image]